Function that use Sliding Window isn`t working
The function should return the length of the maximum substring in which there are no duplicate characters, but the program runs for an infinite amount of time
function findMaxLength(str) {
  let right = 0;
  let left = 0;
  let answer = 0;
  let arr = [];

  while (right < str.length) {
    let ch = str.split("")[right];
    if (!arr.includes(ch)) {
      arr.push(ch);
      answer = Math.max(answer, (right - left + 1));
      right++;
    } else {
      while (arr.includes(ch)) {
        arr.splice(left, 1);
        left++;
      }
    }
  }

  return answer;
}



well, imagine this: there are 2 ch: one is at position 0 and one on 1. left=0 so you splice the ch at position 0, you left++ and repeat: the 2nd ch is now again at position 0, but left is 1, so you keep splicing and incrementing left forever because of the ch at pos 0

In general, you should be using a debugger (or if you don't have that, be putting console.log statements all over your code). You should try to follow your own program mentally (or with the debugger) step by step. This is called "troubleshooting" or "debugging" and is an essential skill.

Oh, another thing! ... arr.splice doesn't even influence the original str! The result of str.split will always be the same because you only modify the resulting array but you never update the string.

The issue is the use of arr.includes(ch) inside the while loop. You are removing elements from arr using arr.splice(left, 1) inside the loop, therefore the condition arr.includes(ch) might not evaluate correctly.
function findMaxLength(str) {
  let right = 0;
  let left = 0;
  let answer = 0;
  let arr = new Set();

  while (right < str.length) {
    let ch = str.charAt(right);
    if (!arr.has(ch)) {
      arr.add(ch);
      answer = Math.max(answer, right - left + 1);
      right++;
    } else {
      arr.delete(str.charAt(left));
      left++;
    }
  }

  return answer;
}

console.log(findMaxLength("abaadfa"));
console.log(findMaxLength("qoeurqoiwukajsdflj"));
console.log(findMaxLength("uuuuaaauuu"));



As an alternative, are you familiar with the lcs algorithm? It might suit your use case if we modify it slightly:


function lcs(a, b) {
  const m = a.length + 1;
  const n = b.length + 1;

  const weights = new Array(m).fill(0).map(() => new Array(n).fill(0));
  const paths = new Array(m - 1).fill(0).map(() => new Array(n - 1).fill(""));

  for (let i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1]) {
        weights[i][j] = weights[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
        paths[i - 1][j - 1] = "\u2196";
      } else if (weights[i - 1][j] >= weights[i][j - 1]) {
        weights[i][j] = weights[i - 1][j];
        paths[i - 1][j - 1] = "\u2191";
      } else {
        weights[i][j] = weights[i][j - 1];
        paths[i - 1][j - 1] = "\u2190";
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    weights,
    paths
  };
}

const args = document.querySelectorAll(".arg");

for (let arg of args) {
  const text = arg.firstElementChild.innerText;
  const maxs = [1];

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length - 1; i++) {
    const seen = [text[i]];

    for (let j = i + 1; j < text.length; j++) {
      if (seen.includes(text[j])) {
        break;
      }

      const res = lcs(text, text.slice(i, j + 1))["weights"];
      maxs.push(res[res.length - 1][res[0].length - 1]);
      seen.push(text[j]);
    }
  }

  maxs.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const elm = document.createElement("div");
  elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${maxs[maxs.length - 1]}`));
  arg.appendChild(elm);
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.arg {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 10px;
}
<div class="arg">
  <div><!-- should match "obar" -->
    foobar
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arg">
  <div><!-- should match "fo" -->
    foofoo
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arg">
  <div><!-- edgde case, return 1 -->
    a
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arg">
  <div></div><!-- edgde case, should probably return nonsensical value -->
</div>



Note that the paths array in the algorithm isn't needed for your use case, I simply lifted the code from here
